# How to make use of Connection string in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I am a beginner in ASP. Please help me in this simple concept. How to store a connection string in web.config and how to make use of it in in ADO.NET while connecting to SQL 2008 DB?

Comment: There are variety of complex answers available. I wanted a simple straight forward answer. If anybody knows it, redirects me to such link, I will be really kind to them. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi please check the code below:

In Asp.Net 2.0

```
 You can add a key inside appSettings. 

<appSettings>
<add key="ConnectionStringName" value="server=localhost; database=DatabaseName; uid=SqlInstanceUserName; password=SqlInstancePassword;" />
</appSettings>

To read the connection string: 

string connStr = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("ConnectionStringName");
```

In Asp.Net 3.5

```
 You can add a key inside connectionStrings. 

<connectionStrings>
<add name="ConnectionStringName" connectionString="server=localhost; database=DatabaseName; uid=SqlInstanceUserName; password=Sq lInstancePassword;" />
</connectionStrings>

To read the connection string:
```

string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringName"].ConnectionString;

Answer (score 0):

This SO answer has some good pointers about connection strings. [How to define a connection string to a SQL Server 2008 database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3159093/how-to-define-a-connection-string-to-a-sql-server-2008-database).
This MSDN documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494(v=vs.110).aspx has information about connection strings and examples also in the configuration files.